# Angular2/Typescript: access instance variable from the chaining observable function

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm using Angular2 with Typescript. Say I have a dummy login component and an authentication service to do token authentication. I'm going to set the `authenticated` variable in one of the `map` function as soon as I get the token from backend server.

The question is that I can't access the instance variable inside the chaining function. The `this` inside the chaining function is actually the subscriber of this observable. I know this's a scope issue but can't figure it out.

```
export class AuthenticationService {
authenticated:boolean = false; //this is the variable I want to access

constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.authenticated = !!sessionStorage.getItem('auth_token');
}

login(username, password) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
      .post(
        'http://localhost:8080/token-auth',
        JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        { headers }
      )
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((res) => { 
        if (res) {
            this.authenticated = true;  //this is where I want to access the instance variable
            sessionStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.token);
        }

        return res;
      });
}
```

The dummy-login component where the above `login()` method is called is like this:

```
export class DummyLoginComponent {
  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {
  }

  onSubmit(username, password) {

    this.auth.login(username, password).subscribe((result) => {
        if (result) {
            this.router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34948742/215945

Comment: @MarkRajcok not really, I have subscribed this observable inside another component. What I really want to do is to set the `authenticated` instance variable to true inside the `.map()` function.

Comment: Where's the code that invokes `login`? Either fix that code, or make `login` an arrow function

Comment: Why do you think it does not work? Arrow functions capture this from context.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I posted the dummy-login component where the `login()` is called. How to fix it?

Comment: @kemsky Because in debug, the `this` inside the `map()` function is a `MapSubscriber` which apparently doesn't have `authenticated` variable

Comment: debugger might be slightly off (wrong line due to sourcemaps), try to add logging for `this.auth.authenticated` in `DummyLoginComponent`.

Comment: @kemsky Yeah, you're right. `this.auth.authenticated` is as expected. This is not a valid question any more. Don't know how to close this question though.

Comment: To delete your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/how-can-i-delete-my-question

Answer (score 1):

You can just subscribe to the observable instead of mapping it

```
login(username, password) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let res = this.http
      .post(
        'http://localhost:8080/token-auth',
        JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        { headers }
      )
      .map(res => res.json());
    res.subscribe(
      (res) => { 
            this.authenticated = true;  //this is where I want to access the instance variable
            sessionStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.token);
    });
    return res;
}
```