# Angular 2 Post Request to Node/Express Server Endpoint

Tags: node.js, http, express, angular

I can't seem to diagnose why I can't send a successful HTTP request in my Angular 2 Typescript application. I send POST requests successfully through Postman, but the front-end seems to be unhappy about linking to the back-end... there's no error, and the back-end never responds. Please help!

I'm working in a C9 environment.

Here's my current implementation:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MessageBody} from '../message-body/message-body';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'signup',
  template: require('app/signup/signup.html'),
  styles: [require('app/signup/signup.css')],
  viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  providers: []
})

export class Signup {
  model = new MessageBody(
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '');
  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }
  onSubmit() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    this.http.post('/email', JSON.stringify(this.model), {headers: headers})
      .map(res => console.log(res.json()));
  }
}
```

This is the endpoint on the server:

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/email', sendEmail);

app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/../dist'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT, listen);
```

I've tried posting to `/email`, `http://localhost:8080/email`, `https://{appName}-{username}.c9users.io/email`, all to no avail!

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate the help!

EDIT: Thierry already answered here, so this is a dupe.
[angular2: http post not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948681/angular2-http-post-not-executing)

Comment: Is this the same URL + port your application is initially loaded from?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the content type and the content you provide to the POST method.

If you expect url-encoded form, you need to update your code this way:

```
onSubmit() {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  var content = new URLSearchParams();
  content.set('somefield', this.model.somefield);
  (...)

  this.http.post('/email', content.toString(), {headers: headers})
  .map(res => console.log(res.json()));
}
```

If you want to send JSON content, just change the value of the `Content-Type` header:

```
onSubmit() {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  this.http.post('/email', JSON.stringify(this/model), {headers: headers})
  .map(res => console.log(res.json()));
}
```

Moreover I think that you endpoint isn't located on the same machine unless you serve it through your Express application with something like this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @thierry! Just for clarification purposes, if I send 'application/json' as my Content-Type, why wouldn't my previous implementation work? I tried that as well.

I'm trying your implementation now. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: You're welcome! What do you mean by "previous implementation"?

Comment: Ah, your edit answered my question. I was essentially asking if it would work had I replaced my content type with 'application/json' versus what I used in the above ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded').

Unfortunately neither of your suggestions worked...

A few more debugging notes: I know I'm hitting the onSubmit function because I've tried logging in there, and this.http.post is also the function I expect, but it seems like my backend is NEVER accepting a POST request through the app. But it does accept it through Postman

FYI there is an edit in the solution: JSON.stringify(this.model)

Comment: Okay! Can you see your request within the network tab of dev tools?

Comment: Could you try to move `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in the `bootstrap` function? Or within the `providers` attribute of your component?

Comment: Provided more information about my server up above. I think the back-end is structured correctly.

To answer your question, no request is being made through the network tab. I forgot to mention that. Trying your suggestion now.

Comment: Yes, that's strange! I would debug the Angular2 source code itself and specially the `src/http/backends/xhr_backend.ts` file (class `XHRConnection`) by putting a breakpoint in it. I wrote an article on how to do this: https://medium.com/@ttemplier/how-to-debug-the-typescript-source-code-of-angular2-99a593e2983f#.x338h43ve.

Comment: You'll be able to see if there is a problem with the underlying XHR object used by Angular2 to execute the request. See https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/http/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L33

Comment: You already answered the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948681/angular2-http-post-not-executing

;)

Comment: Oh yes. Observables are lady. You need to subscribe to execute them ;-) Pleased to hear that this fixed your problem!

Comment: Thank you so much @ThierryTemplier ! What i was missing is the `toString()` / `JSON.stringify(...)` of the body of the request! Why wasn't it working without these methods? This is because of the `headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`? Thank you again, it works perfectly! :)