# How to make post request from angular to node server

Tags: node.js, angular, http

When I print contents of request on Node server, I can't see the user data anywhere.

Here is my Node server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer( function (request, response) {  
    console.log(request);
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

And here is Angular2 code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Http, Response, Headers , RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry'; // to be able to retry when error occurs
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Angular Test';
  user = { id : 1, name : "Hello"};
  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    console.log(this.user);

    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/", this.user, options)
    .subscribe( 
    (err) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log("Success"); 
    });
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out or explain how to handle http request in angular.

Comment: Are you using express framework in Node.JS?

Comment: there are few things missing in your code(like nodeserver implementation, router for post, map and subscribe the post call etc..).  refer these links, will help you. [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680700/angular-2-post-request-to-node-express-server-endpoint), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948681/angular2-http-post-not-executing) and this [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular)

Comment: Are you using expressjs with your nodejs?

Comment: @Darshita I'm not using express.js in Node. Is it better?

Comment: @echonax. No, I'm not. Is it better.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That is your server:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}) );

app.all("/*", function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  next();
});

app.post('/ping', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.body)
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

That is your angular client:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user = { id : 1, name : 'Hello'};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  callServer() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/ping', JSON.stringify(this.user), {
      headers: headers
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

repo https://github.com/kuncevic/angular-httpclient-examples

Answer (score 4):

I've written this inside our documentation page but since it is deprecated now I'll copy it here.

Your node part, app.js, should look like (assuming you are using expressjs along with node.js):

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function(){
    console.log("Server connected. Listening on port: " + (process.env.PORT || 8080));
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}) );

app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/front' ) );

app.post('/test', function(req,res){ //**** http request receiver ****
  var myTestVar = "Hello World";
  return res.send(myTestVar);
});

//send the index.html on every page refresh and let angular handle the routing
app.get('/*',  function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Reloading");
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname }); 
});
```

With this node configs when you post something to `localhost:8080/test`, you will receive `myTestVar` as a response in your subscribe callback.