# How to POST from angular 2 to express server

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Newbie here trying to get a grasp on sending contact form data from Angular 2 to a Node/Express server... Right now I'm hosting Angular 2 with the built-in server at localhost:4200, and the express server at localhost:3000. I tried the following code but am getting the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\corey\Desktop\Project\server\api\contact-form-submit'
```

Here is my contact-form.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
})
export class ContactFormComponent {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    onSubmit(form) {
        this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/server/api/contact-form-submit', JSON.stringify(form.value)).subscribe();
        console.log(form.value);
    }


}
```

Here is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var mg = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//trying to get contact form submission from angular 2 form here
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./api/contact-form-submit');
    console.log('test');
});

//api key and domain for mailgun
var auth = {
  auth: {
    api_key: 'api-key-here',
    domain: 'mailgun@domain here'
  }
}

//trying to send email with nodemailer here
app.post('./api/send', function(req, res) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(auth));

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'postmaster@email.com',
        to: 'email@goeshere.com',
        subject: 'Website submission',
        text: 'Name: ' + req.body.name + 'Email: ' + req.body.email + 'Message: ' + req.body.message,
        html: '<p>Submission: </p><br><ul><li>Name: ' + req.body.name + '</li><li>Email: ' + req.body.email + '</li><li>Message: ' + req.body.message + '</li></ul>' 
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent.');
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    })

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express started on port 3000');
});
```

I get successful form data to use within Angular 2, and I had the express server  sending emails with a regular express post/get with html files... but I'm not understanding a key part of how to integrate Angular with Express and use it to send an email with Nodemailer. Any help here? Thanks. [This is my project structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwO77.png)

Comment: try chaning your api route url from `app.post('./api/send', ` to be `app.post('/api/send', ` (without the dot)

Comment: also the error might be because the server cannot file the file you want from this line `res.sendfile('./api/contact-form-submit');`. Since it's trying to read from the file system and, maybe, the file isn't there so it's throwing the error that it cannot find a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was answering to the similar question [How to make post request from angular to node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747412/how-to-make-post-request-from-angular-to-node-server)

When you post from angular you need to configure `cross-origin` on your server.

Checkout this github repo https://github.com/kuncevic/angular-httpclient-examples for that matter