# Can't Get Response From Http in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular-http

i need help in getting a response from http during ngOnInit(). I put an alert("hello") and it's not alerting anything. Is there something wrong in my code?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

    return this.http
      .get('http://sampeleposts', { headers })
      .map(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          alert("hello");
        },
        error => {
          alert(error.text());
          console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you look for errors in the Console?

Comment: @nitind. Theres nothing in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `.subscribe()`

```
return this.http
      .get('http://sampeleposts', { headers })
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          alert("hello");
        },
        error => {
          alert(error.text());
          console.log(error.text());
        }
      );
```

That is how observables works. If you won't subscribe it won't executed

**UPDATE:**
Here is `"how to http"` taking from [How to make post request from angular to node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747412/how-to-make-post-request-from-angular-to-node-server):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user = { id : 1, name : 'Hello'};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  callServer() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/ping', JSON.stringify(this.user), {
      headers: headers
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

> The example above is using the new `'@angular/common/http'` shipped in
>   Angular `4.3+` so as you mentioned in comments you are already using
>   one of these versions so I would recommend to switch to `HttpClient`
>   then.

Comment: Where do i add it? How do i write it?

Comment: Thank you. it now says token not provided. Is there wrong in my let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

Comment: @Joseph I just updated the answer with some details using new `@angular/common/http` It is showing how to pass `HttpHeaders()` right. Also you might use `http interceptors` to do that, if you want https://angular.io/guide/http#advanced-usage.

Comment: @Joseph are you using angular 4.3+ btw?

Comment: Yes. But i'm still using the http only. But I heard HttpClient is the new one.

Comment: @Joseph yes it is new one whipped in Angular `4.3`, I would recommend to use that. Just follow the example I provided to switch to that.

Comment: I have a service file that uses http. Could you help me convert that? I can edit my post here or i would ask a new question?

Comment: @Joseph Create a new question and post the link here in comments I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll just add link here.

Comment: I cannot post again for 90 mins :(.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153724/discussion-between-kuncevic-and-joseph).