# Errors when making HttpClient Get Request from Angular Front-End to Node.js Back-End

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, http

I receive the error: Cannot GET / displayed on my local host url when trying to make the HttpClient get request from my front-end in Angular to my back-end endpoint in Node.js. My back-end endpoint is displaying the correct data from my MongoDB database, but I am facing these issues when trying to connect the back-end to the front-end.

Node Back-end Code:

```
app.get("/temp/route1", (req, res, next) => {
   myDatabaseCollection.find({ number: "10" }).then(pages => {
      res.status(200).json({
        items: pages
      });
    });
  });
```

Angular Code in app.component.ts (adapted from: [How to make post request from angular to node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747412/how-to-make-post-request-from-angular-to-node-server)) :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-tool';
  user = { id : 1, name : "Hello"};

  getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:1025/temp/route1', JSON.stringify(this.user), {})
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

It would be great if anybody would be able to help me with this!

Comment: what are the issues?

Comment: you are returning a 404 status code.Why?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe returning 404 from express is the reason for that error

Comment: I am missing too many information from your code: `headers`, `this.user`, do you have a constructor and an ngOnInit method or anything from where you do call your `this.getData(...)` method?

Comment: I'm not even sure how that code could compile, since you're passing 3 arguments to the HtttpClient.get(), but get() only expects 2.

Comment: I am returning a status 200, not 404 – sorry about the mistake in the code. Also, the error is that I am trying to call the server route through the get method in my angular code, and it is not able to find it and log that data. In addition, I cleaned up the issues regarding the header and this.user ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

add constructor `constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-tool';
  user = { id : 1, name : "Hello"};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:1025/temp/route1', JSON.stringify(this.user), {})
    .subscribe(
       (response: any) => {
          console.log(response);
        },
        (error: any) => {
         console.log(error);
        }
    );
  }
}
```