# Send post request with Angular , catch data with javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9

I need to send http post request at Angular9 app and catch data from a javascript file with ajax javascript. Problem occured bc of i'm running two different ports in a application on the frontend side and need to send data between these two ports. One side of app is angular , other side is javascript. Could you recommend to me some documentation or advice?

Comment: So are you having a CORS issue?

Comment: I don't know how to go step by step to make a call from angular9 and catch data with javascript ajax . I didnt pass this step still so i don't have Cors issue yet. @AlonEitan

Comment: This seems similar to my issue : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747412/how-to-make-post-request-from-angular-to-node-server/45750366