# http post error: Uncaught TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do a POST in angular 2 using:

```
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) ;
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this._http.post(this._healthFromControllerJsonPostUrl + "/MyAction", JSON.stringify("asdf"), options);
```

I'm using es6

```
"module": "es6"
```

I get this error

```
this._http.__proto__.post.arguments:
    Uncaught TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.
        at eval (eval at evaluate (:85:21), <anonymous>:1:26)
```

I've verified that my URL is correct. I found some articles that this is because of es6 and strict mode.

- in this case, should I disabled strict mode?
- how can I get around this error?

Comment: Are you sure `_healthFromControllerJsonPostUrl` is not a function :)?

Comment: I was looking in the wrong place. This is what solved my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948681/angular2-http-post-not-executing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: http post not executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948681/angular2-http-post-not-executing)

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe something like this:

```
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class myServiceClass {

private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
constructor(private http: Http) {};

this.http
      .post(this._healthFromControllerJsonPostUrl, JSON.stringify('asdf'), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data)
      .catch(this.handleError);

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

As I didn't see your complete component I don't really know if your issue is related to how you make the call, to how you instance or you use dependencies... So I decided to post a simple example hoping that helps you, if it doesn't, don't hesitate to put more information so we can find out what's the source of your issue.

Hope it helped! ;)

Comment: I have my project working so that http get operations work correctly. It's just when I do the post I get this error.