# Angular2 Final release Http Post not working in MVC

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-router, angular2-services

I am not able to call a MVC APIController from the Angular Service. Can anybody help. Thank you.

My Route.Config is as shown below.I am allowing all routes.

```
public class RouteConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*anything}",     //"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

When i am calling the post from the Application its not working not throwing any error also.

Code from forms.service.ts file

```
    createForm(post: myForm) {

    console.log('Actual object: ' + JSON.stringify(post));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(post));
    return this._http.post(this._posturl, JSON.stringify(post)).map(response => response.json());
    }
```

Code from API Controller

```
  public class MinPostController : ApiController
{
   public MinPostController()
    {

    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateForm([FromBody] PostFormModel input)
    {
         //Check if the post is hitting.
         bool status = false; 
    }

}
```

When i post the Json using the Fiddler it works fine as shown below.Please find the images below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What "Network" tab show when you hit F12?

Comment: @CodeNotFound  I have attached the image of network tab. When i click on the post nothing new is coming in the network tab

Comment: Are you sure the `http.post` has been called in your component? In other words, have you used a `subscribe`?

Comment: onSubmit() {
        this._formsService.createForm(this.myform.value);  
    }  
Above method gets called when a button is clicked in my component.ts

Comment: I didnt use any subscribe method

Answer (score 0):

Could you add `Content-Type` in header, and see any different?

```
return this._http.post(this._posturl, JSON.stringify(post), this.getRequestOptions())
   .map(response => response.json())
   .catch(this.handleError);

private getRequestOptions() {
   return new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers({
         "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
  });
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
   console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: I tried....I still didnt figure out whats the problem.
Where as GET is working without any problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. I have to create a observable and then subscribe it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34948742/6707243