# no http request to server ANGULAR

Tags: angular, http, post

hello guys here is my likePost function

```
likePost(post){
    let head = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Authorization":"JWT "+localStorage.getItem("token")

  });
  let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: head});
  // this.http.post(this.likeurl,requestOptions)

  this.http.post(this.likeurl+post.id+'/like',requestOptions)
```

here is my post.html

```
<button mat-button (click)="likePost(post)">LIKE</button>
```

but when i clicked on  my like button in the angular app i couldnt see any kind of requests by angular to my server
and when i checked it in myserver nothing has changed

BTW the link when once fired will create a like by that user in myserver for that angular should just browse it once and the like will be added

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: http post not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948681/angular2-http-post-not-executing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call **`subscribe`** on the observable,

```
this.http.post(this.likeurl+post.id+'/like',requestOptions).subscribe((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
});
```